# PySide Installation on Archlinux

Tags: installation, pyside, archlinux

I want to install PySide on Archlinux. I've added it to my pacman.conf as described here: http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/PySide_Binaries_Linux

But this doesn't work:

```
:: Synchronisiere Paketdatenbanken...
 core ist aktuell
 extra ist aktuell
 community ist aktuell
 multilib ist aktuell
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'pyside.db' nicht von dev.archlinux.org übertragen : Not Found
Fehler: Konnte pyside nicht aktualisieren (Not Found)
:: Starte komplette Systemaktualisierung...
Fehler: Konnte Datei /var/lib/pacman/sync/pyside.db nicht öffnen: Failed to open '/var/lib/pacman/sync/pyside.db'
Fehler: Konnte Datei /var/lib/pacman/sync/pyside.db nicht öffnen: Failed to open '/var/lib/pacman/sync/pyside.db'
 Es gibt nichts zu tun
```

Any Ideas how to get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repository from that link isn't working or updated anymore, you'll have to build the package pyside yourself from Arch User Repository (AUR) - see the [Arch Linux wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_User_Repository#Installing_packages) for instructions.